# Deixar o vídeo ocupando 100% da tela com altura fixa

Tags: html5, html5-video

Gente gostaria de saber como faço para deixar um video 100% da tela com altura fixa sem que ele fique menor igual a imagem abaixo [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A ideia é que o vídeo ocupe todo esse espaço em cinza claro se eu deixo o video sem uma altura fica ele fica 100% da tela porem fica com a altura muito grande e se uso um tamanho fixo igual o da imagem ele fica da altura certa do `container` mais não fica com a largura 100% preenchida segue um pedaço do meu código

```
<video src="http://localhost/trustech/image/catalog/video-academia.mp4" muted="true" autoplay="true" loop="true" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Esse português ai está complicando o entendimento. Veja se é isso http://kithomepage.com/sos/video100.htm

Comment: e mais ou menos a ideia amigo e que meu video fique na quela sessão toda como mostra na imagem acima so que assim se uso width:100%; ele fica enorme o video deixando a sessão completamente grande agora se uso width:100; com uma altura de height: 550px; ele fica no tamanho correto da minha sessão mais ele acaba não ocupando toda aquela sessão sei que é dificil de explicar assim mais consegue entender agora ?

Answer (score -1):

usando css

```
video {
  position: fixed; /*  absolute ou fixed */
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

ou style

```
  <video style="position: fixed; /*  absolute ou fixed */width: 100%;z-index: 20;height: 100%;left: 0px;top: 0px;" src="http://localhost/trustech/image/catalog/video-academia.mp4" muted="true" autoplay="true" loop="true" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;">
```

Your browser does not support the video tag.

Comment: Penso que ele não quer que o vídeo acompanhe o scroll, mas que tenha uma altura fixe, pergunta um pouco confusa.

Answer (score -2):

Olá. Você pode usar isso:

```css
body{
            background-color: red;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        video{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" controls></video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).